# The system of logarithmic equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, systems-of-equations

> I have no idea how to solve the following system of equations:
>   $$\begin{cases}\log_{|xy|}{(x-y)}=1\\ 2\log_{5}{|xy|}\log_{|xy|}{(x+y)}=1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Well $log_b a = 1$ means $a = b^1 = b$.  so $|xy| = x-y$.  That's one heck of a conditional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that for $|xy|\neq0,1$

$$2\log_{5}{|xy|}\log_{|xy|}{(x+y)}=1\iff  \frac{\log_{|xy|}{(x+y)^2}}{\log_{|xy|}{5}}=1\iff \log_{|xy|}{(x+y)^2}=\log_{|xy|}{5}$$

$$\implies (x+y)^2=5$$

and

$$\log_{|xy|}{(x-y)}=1 \implies x-y = |xy|$$

thus

- $(x+y)^2=5\implies x+y=\sqrt 5$ since x+y>0 for existence of $\log$
- $x-y = |xy|$  consider 2 cases

1) $xy>0$

$\implies x-y=xy\implies x +(x-\sqrt 5)=x(\sqrt 5-x) \implies x^2+(2-\sqrt 5)x-\sqrt 5=0$

$\implies x_1=\frac{\sqrt 5 +1}{2}\quad x_2=\frac{\sqrt 5-5}{2} \implies y_1=\frac{\sqrt 5 -1}{2}\quad y_2=\frac{\sqrt 5+5}{2}$

2) $xy<0$

$\implies x-y=-xy\implies x +(x-\sqrt 5)=-x(\sqrt 5-x) \implies x^2-(2+\sqrt 5)x+\sqrt 5=0$

$\implies x_1=\frac{\sqrt 5 -1}{2}\quad x_2=\frac{5+\sqrt 5}{2} \implies y_1=\frac{\sqrt 5 +1}{2}\quad y_2=\frac{-5+\sqrt 5}{2}$

Comment: $x+y>0\Rightarrow x+y=\sqrt{5}$ and from the first $x-y=|xy|$ Now we have the following system: \begin{cases}x+y=\sqrt{5}\\x-y=|xy|\end{cases} and that's where I am stuck. I split it to the following systems: 
1.$\begin{cases}x+y=\sqrt{5}\\x-y=xy\end{cases}$
2.$\begin{cases}x+y=\sqrt{5}\\y-x=xy\end{cases}$

Comment: in 1. I get solution $x_{1}=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$ $y_{1}=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$ and this is incorrect beacuse $xy \neq1$ and the other solution is $x_{2}=\frac{\sqrt{5}-5}{2}$ $y_{2}=\frac{\sqrt{5}+5}{2}$ and this one is also incorrect beacuse $x-y>0$
in 2. it is complicate.. It takes a lot of time and this problem shouldn't be time taker.. 
and Result in book is: $x=\frac{\sqrt{5}+5}{2}$ $y=\frac{\sqrt{5}-5}{2}$ What I have done wrong?

Comment: @NemanjaDjordjevic I check what I obtain!

Comment: @NemanjaDjordjevic Yes from the first system we do not obtain solutions from the second we should obtain as accepltable $x=\frac{\sqrt{5}+5}{2}$ and $y=\frac{\sqrt{5}-5}{2}$

Comment: 1. $x^{2}-(\sqrt{5}-2)x-\sqrt{5}=0$
$x_{1,2}=\frac{\sqrt{5}-2 \pm \sqrt{(\sqrt{5}-2)^{2}+4\sqrt{5}}}{2}$
$x_{1,2}=\frac{\sqrt{5}-2 \pm 3}{2}$

Comment: @NemanjaDjordjevic ops yes I've inverted a sign!

Comment: Why I am getting that $x=\frac{\sqrt{5}-5}{2}$ and not $x=\frac{\sqrt{5}+5}{2}$ as it should be?

Comment: You should obtain it from the second system for xy<0.

Comment: Ok, probably I made a mistake because I am tired, thanks on effort!

Comment: @NemanjaDjordjevic I'm tired too, You have made a good work! tomorrow you will conclude better! You are welcome, Bye

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$\log_5(|xy|) = \frac{1}{\log_{|xy|}(5)}.$$
Consequently,
$$2\log_{5}{|xy|}\log_{|xy|}{(x+y)}=1 \implies x+y =\sqrt{5}.$$
And
$$\log_{|xy|}{(x-y)}=1 \implies x-y = |xy|.$$

Comment: Nice hint, I was giving a very complicate way!

Comment: that's exactly what I got, now I split it to the two systems: $x+y=\sqrt{5} \land x-y=xy$ or $x+y=\sqrt{5} \land y-x=xy $ is everything ok here? but I got the wrong solutions..

Comment: @NemanjaDjordjevic You are on the right track. There might be some extraneous solutions.

Comment: Don't think we can assume $xy > 0$.  We know $x +y > 0$ and $x-y > 0$ so $x > y$ and $x > -y$ so $x > |y| \ge 0$ but we don't know that $y$ is positive.

Comment: $x = |xy| +y \implies y(1 \pm x) = x \implies y = \frac {x}{1\pm x}\lor 1\pm x = 0\land y=0$.  $x + \frac {x}{1\pm x} = \sqrt 5$ will be solvable via quadratic equation.  (and $y = 0; 1\pm x = 0$ is incompatible with $x + y = \sqrt 5$.).

Answer (score 0):

$$1=2\cdot\log_{5}{|xy|}\log_{|xy|}{(x+y)}$$

Using change of base on $\log_5|xy|\implies\dfrac{1}{\log_{|xy|}5}$

$$1=2\cdot\dfrac{1}{\log_{|xy|}5}\cdot\log_{|xy|}{(x+y)}\implies 1=2\cdot\dfrac{\log_{|xy|}(x+y)}{\log_{|xy|}5}\implies1=2\cdot\log_5(x+y)$$

Note that $\dfrac{\log_{|xy|}(x+y)}{\log_{|xy|}5}=\log_5(x+y)$ because of change of base.